# Non-object-oriented game tutorials

Tags: oop

I've been tasked with writing an essay extolling the virtues of object oriented programming and creating an accompanying game to demonstrate them.

My initial idea is to find a tutorial for a simple game written in a programming language which does not follow the OOP paradigm (or written in an OOP language but not in an OOP way) and recreate it in an OOP way using either C# or Java (haven't yet decided). This would then allow me to make concrete comparisons between the two.

The game doesn't have to be anything complex; Tetris, Pong, etc. that sort of thing. The problem I've had so far is finding a suitable tutorial, any suggestions?

Comment: ohh no.. ooohh nooo its not fit to so .....

Comment: Perhaps you could try looking up gaming tutorials for C or Basic? If I recall correctly, none of them are really OOP (although you could certainly fake it in C). As a side note, you might be able to get a better response at [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) or perhaps [gamedev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you found source code for a game not in OOP. There are some OOP virtues that you can point out in your essay:

**Organization.**
Since a game has many tasks, it is a good idea to assign a responsibility to one class. This means write one class that keeps score, one class that does file access (reading and writing game state, for example), classes to represent your characters, etc. Otherwise, you will have one huge text file with thousands of lines of code. It would be a nightmare to even look at it, let alone find what you need and fix it.

**Encapsulation.**
This is grouping together properties and functions for better organization. We used to have a different array to store each property - (example) one array for aircraft names, one array for firepower, another array for top speed, etc. That sucks because you need to make sure that the same index across all those arrays actually describes the correct aircraft. It's better to create an Aircraft object and give it those property names. You'll then have one array that holds aircraft - no need to keep track of too many arrays.

**Reusability.**
As you write more games (and even other apps), you will come across the need to reuse classes. For example, you would use the same Card class in your Solitaire game as any card game you'll write in the future.

**Polymorphism/Inheritance.**
Say that you want to display each character - both heroes and villains in some sort of a grid. You will want both Hero and Villain to inherit Character. Character will have common properties and even a[n abstract] Display() function. You would then write the custom Display() function for Character and Villain (that access class-specific data for drawing). You then create an array of Character objects, and you may store either a Villain or Hero in each slot. When the game goes through that list to display, each item.Display() call will automatically pick the correct Display() function based on the Character's actual type. Try to do this without OOP and you'll end up with a long if-else (and probably even nested) statement and all drawing routines in one place.

That's just from the type of my head from experience in general programming that you can definitely apply in game programming. There are probably more OOP aspects than mentioned, so you may want to research. Best of everything for your essay!

Comment: I've still yet to find a suitable tutorial in something like BASIC, but I'm looking. But thanks for the pointers, those were along the lines I was going to write the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can try grabbing a (simple) TI-Basic game from [TICalc](http://ticalc.org), [Omnimaga](http://www.omnimaga.org/), or most other calculator programming websites and try to understand its code.

Answer (score 0):

Try a BASIC game from this site:

http://www.atariarchives.org/basicgames/